# Extension - Error (Swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, extension-methods

I have code to calculate the factor.

I'm trying to do this from another file "**String+Factorial.swift**" using 
**Extension** but I get an error.

How to remove it?

Not yet dismantled with Extension

[image]

ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func FactorialButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentInput = factorial(currentInput: currentInput)
}
```

String+Factorial.swift

```
import Foundation

extension Double {

func factorial(currentInput: Double) -> Double {
    if currentInput >= 0 {
        return currentInput == 0 ? 1 : currentInput * self.factorial(currentInput: currentInput - 1)
    } else {
        return 0 / 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: call     `currentInput = currentInput.factorial(currentInput: currentInput)`

Comment: one simple question if you sent the double value as `3.0` you get the OP as 6.0 correct or else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood the concept of extensions. If you extend an existing type with a function, that function will be an instance function of the type (unless of course you define it as a class/static function), so you need to call the function on an instance of the class.

In your case, you need to call `factorial` on `currentInput` like this:
`currentInput = currentInput.factorial(currentInput: currentInput)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what extensions are.

If you have the `factorial` method inside a `Double` extension, you will be able to use it like so:

```
6.0.factorial()
```

Not like:

```
factorial(currentInput: 6.0)
```

Your current method tries to do both. Your current method can only be used like this:

```
6.0.factorial(currentInput: 6.0)
```

which makes little sense.

This is how you should have implemented it.

```
func factorial() -> Double {
  if self >= 0 {
    return self == 0 ? 1 : self * (self - 1).factorial()
  } else {
    return 0 / 0
  }
}
```

Note how every `currentInput` is replaced with `self`. In a `Double` extension, `self` is a double, the double that you are calling the method on.

Now you can call it like this:

```
currentInput.factorial()
```

However, doing a factorial on a `Double` is a little weird in my opinion. `Double`s are inaccurate and when you subtract by 1 a lot of times this inaccuracy becomes obvious. You might get `-0.0000000000000001` eventually instead of `0`. This will cause the `>= 0` to fail and return NaN.

This is just my opinion, but I think doing `factorial` as a global function is more readable, like this:

```
factorial(6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code,
it will work fine

```
@IBAction func FactorialButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
currentInput = currentInput.factorial(currentInput: currentInput)}
```